# Threading TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running two python jobs scheduled at intervals.
`activity_url_collector` and `storage_data_collector` are the `.py` files in the same directory as of `index.py`.

Below is **index.py**:

```
import schedule
import time
import psycopg2
import threading
import activity_url_collector
import storage_data_collector

def main():


    def run_threaded(job_func):
        job_thread = threading.Thread(target=job_func)
        job_thread.start()

    schedule.every(3).minutes.do(run_threaded, activity_url_collector)
    schedule.every(3).minutes.do(run_threaded, storage_data_collector)

    schedule.run_all()

    print('Post-Processing-Application is running')

    while True:
            schedule.run_pending()
            time.sleep(1)    

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**Detailed Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

What could be going wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to run `activity_url_collector` and `storage_data_collector` in a thread.

Looking at your import both are modules (Python files) which can be run by the interpreter directly, but they are not "callables" as needed for your case.

You can run functions, methods or any object that implements `__call__` in a thread. As a solution you could add a `main()` function to your modules which does the actual work and use `activity_url_collector.main` as the target for the thread.